# Changing setState in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

How does one show a counter going from 1 to 2 to 3 to n on the click of a button. I've tried doing a setState in a for loop but thats not worked.
I know react's setState is async, i've even tried to use prevState, but its not worked.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = {
      counter: 0

      };

      this.startCounter = this.startCounter.bind(this);
    }

    startCounter() {
      const self = this;
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          const counter = prevState.counter + 1;
          return Object.assign({}, prevState, {counter: counter})
        });
      }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              Counter Value: {this.state.counter}
               <button onClick={this.startCounter}>Start Counter</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

webpack bin below

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkU1NJA-ectflyDgf_S

I want to increase the count from 0 to n as a timer of sorts when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

When you run the `startCounter()` function, you start the interval which increments the `counter` value by 1, each second. Once it reaches `n` (5 in this example), it resets.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.interval;
    this.state = {
      counter: 1,
      n: 5
    };
  }

  startCounter = () => {
    if (this.interval) return; //if the timer is already running, do nothing.
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      let c = (this.state.counter % this.state.n) + 1;
      this.setState({
        counter: c
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval); //remove the interval if the component is unmounted.
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        Counter Value: {this.state.counter}
        <button onClick={this.startCounter}>Start Counter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This cant be done without a `setInterval`  just using a for loop.

Comment: @NitishPhanse, do you want it to automatically count upwards or +1 on each click?

Comment: No, that would be straight forward.. i want it to increase from 0 to N(here 100) when i click as a timer. First 1 then 2 ..100

Comment: So like I've done above, right? No, you have to do this with an `interval`. Setting state inside a for-loop is bad practice in many many ways. The biggest issue being computers would finish that loop before you could say Jack Robinson. :) **This ^** is how you do it.

Comment: @NitishPhanse, what happens when the counter reaches `n`?

Comment: Yes i know, cause every time the render method will be fired. After it reached n the counter stops.. Anyway thanks.. :)

Comment: So ill tell you what the exact use case is i've written a genetic algorithm in javascript https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkUr58K-GD0--jQCV9x
Run the above with `babel-node gene.js` in your terminal. You'll see the generations in the terminal. Im trying to replicate the same thing in a react ui by changing state. Also uncomment out the last line and call `population.generation();` function

Comment: @NitishPhanse, this is getting off-topic. You asked something very specific, which I answered quite well I think. You asked for a timer, and I posted how to make a timer. If this is not what you need, then ask a new question and be more specific :)